# Paypal iOS SDK - verify payment

Tags: ios, paypal

I use Paypal SDK to accept credit cards. 
After successful payment I receive PayPalPayment object, which holds Confirmation of payment:

```
{
  "proof_of_payment": {
    "rest_api": {
      "state": "approved",
      "payment_id": "API-PAYMENT-ID-1843"
    }
  },
  "payment": {
    "short_description": "Hipster t-shirt",
    "amount": "9.95",
    "currency_code": "USD"
  },
  "client": {
    "platform": "iOS",
    "paypal_sdk_version": "1.0.0",
    "environment": "live",
    "product_name": "PayPal iOS SDK"
  }
}
```

To verify payment I need to make an API call:

```
curl https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-5YK922393D847794YKER7MUI \
 -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
 -H "Authorization:Bearer ENxom5Fof1KqAffEsXtxwEDa6E1HTEK__KVdIsaCYF8C"
```

I need that `Authorization:Bearer` param, how do I get it?

When I just try to make API call without it I get empty response.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide us the sample code in Objective-C to get the access token and transaction id. We are stuck at this issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is Josh from PayPal. Check out the [PayPal REST API authorization documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/#get-an-access-token). There are also [helper SDKS available](https://github.com/paypal/) for a variety of languages.